# How to use one button to getText and setText to 3 different EditTexts and TextViews

Tags: android, android-studio, button, textview, android-edittext

It's quite simple. I have a button that has an onClickListener which takes a text from EditText, hides it and sets it to TextView which it shows in the same place.
Now, i want to do that to 2 more different edit texts and text views with the same button. Code below.

XML with my buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    tools:context = ".profil"
    android:orientation = "vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:background="@color/pozadina"
        android:id="@+id/rltv">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slikaProfil"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profilna"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textProfil1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/userProfil"
            android:layout_below="@+id/slikaProfil"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rltv">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imeProfil"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Account info"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ime i prezime"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profil"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/imeProfil1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imeProfil"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Upisite ime i prezime"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/imeProfil2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imeProfil1"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Telefon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/telefon"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/telefonProfil1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imeProfil2"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Upisite broj telefona"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/telefonProfil2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/telefonProfil1"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E-mail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/mailProfil1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/telefonProfil2"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Upisite e-mail"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/mailProfil2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mailProfil1"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Adresa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/adresa"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/adresaProfil1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mailProfil2"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Upisite adresu"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/adresaProfil2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adresaProfil1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prihvati"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adresaProfil2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:onClick="zamijeni"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My java file:

```
public class profil extends Fragment {
    private Button dugme4;
    private TextView text1;
    private EditText text2;

    public profil(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profil, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        text1 = view.findViewById(R.id.imeProfil1);
        text2 = view.findViewById(R.id.imeProfil2);
        dugme4 = view.findViewById(R.id.prihvati);

        text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        dugme4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String tekst = text2.getText().toString();
                if (text1.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
                    text1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else if (text2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text1.setText(tekst);
                }


            }
        });


        }
}
```

So as you see i have an if function that on click gets the text, makes the edit text invisible and text visible and at the end sets the text to the textView.

Should i do a few more if functions or should it be done differently.

Comment: On which basis you know, get data from which edittext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this more efficiently by use only a edittext.. no need to use text view.. I am giving a sample demo below

```
    public class profil extends Fragment {
        private Button dugme4;
        //private TextView text1;
        private EditText text2;

        public profil(){

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profil, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

           // text1 = view.findViewById(R.id.imeProfil1);
            text2 = view.findViewById(R.id.imeProfil2);
            dugme4 = view.findViewById(R.id.prihvati);

           // text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            dugme4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (text2.isEnabled()){
                    //make it not editable and non focusable
                    text2.setEnable(false);
                    text2.setCursorVisible(false);
                    //for clearing underline of editText so that it looks like textview
                    text2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
}else{
    text2.setEnabled(true);
    text2.setCursonVisible(true);
 // set any color what you want as underline
    text2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
}
                }
            });


            }
    }
```

Try it.hope it will solve your problem by reducing extra element and complexity.

Comment: I tried this and it looks much better than what i wrote. But i have one problem with it, after i put the text in and press the button it won't let me change it later when i press the button again. So i suppose i need to add on a new click to make it changable again.

Comment: try the new one and let me know

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved the whole problem and looks nice!
I accepted the answer but i can't upvote because i am a new user.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the same logic to access the text from EditText and display it in the TextView, you can make a function which should be called on the click of this button.